# Creating tables with pylons and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pylons

I'm using SQLAlchemy and I can create tables that I have defined in /model/__init__.py but I have defined my classes, tables and their mappings in other files found in the /model directory.

For example I have a profile class and a profile table which are defined and mapped in /model/profile.py

To create the tables I run:

paster setup-app development.ini

But my problem is that the tables that I have defined in /model/__init__.py are created properly but the table definitions found in /model/profile.py are not created. How can I execute the table definitions found in the /model/profile.py so that all my tables can be created?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem with my first real Pylons project.  The solution that worked for me was this:

1. Define tables and classes in your profile.py file
2. In your `__init__.py` add `from profile import *` after your `def init_model`
3. I then added all of my mapper definitions afterwards.  Keeping them all in the init file solved some problems I was having relating between tables defined in different files.

Also, I've since created projects using the declarative method and didn't need to define the mapping in the init file.

Comment: Sweet Christmas, thank you.  I've been having a devil of a time with Pylons because I keep forgetting how to get create_all() to _work._

Answer (score 0):

Just import your other table's modules in your **init**.py, and use metadata object from models.meta in other files. Pylons default setup_app function creates all tables found in metadata object from model.meta after importing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using declarative style, be sure to use Base.meta for tables generation.